# Using actionlistener to call a function from another class

Tags: java, swing, oop, actionlistener

Actionlistener code

```
Player p = new Player();
/**
** Other code here
**/
private static JLabel Status;
final JTextField username = new JTextField(6);
loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {     
           data = username.getText();
                if(p.Login(data)){
        Status.setText(data+" is correct");
    } else {
        Status.setText(data+" is wrong");
    }
         }
      });
```

Player class code

```
  public boolean login(String username){
    if(username == "adam"){
        return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
  }
```

I am always getting that username is wrong no matter what input there is, what should I do? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `equals()` not `==` for comparing your Strings.

Note: **==** checks the reference to the object are equal .

Note: **equals()** This method compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object

[Source for equal function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equals.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in:

```
public boolean login(String username){
    if(username == "adam"){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You need to change:

```
if(username == "adam"){
```

To:

```
if(username.equals("adam")){
```

This is a classic String comparison mistake. Hope this helps :)

Comment: please explain what is going on and not just post up a code answer